# Angular 2 used with JQuery

Tags: angular, angular2-headers

I'm trying to use JQuery with Angular 2 Cli.

I installed JQuery by using `npm install jquery --save` and adding `import $ from 'jquery/dist/jquery'` to app.module.ts.

I get this error in Chrome `Cannot find module 'jquery/dist/jquery'.)`.  But I can find the jquery folder in node_modules.

I'm using JQuery because I want to use [this header](https://codepen.io/Craig-Watson/pen/XbjGex) with shadow effect in my project. I can't find an angular version of this type of header without using Material Design or other UI components (as I prefer not to use this because it changes some of the styling in my project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's another, very simple method to add `jQuery` into your project.

- Include `jQuery` in your `index.html` code.

  `<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>`
- Then just declare it inside specified component:

  `declare let $:any;`

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  But I used `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` instead.

Comment: @todo Of course. I've just used my code, `jQuery` is stored locally in a file in the same folder as `index.html` is :)

Comment: This is really ugly...but it's easy, fast, and it works! :D You can also add the optional integrity attr if you want, like: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

Import the types for jQuery so that the TypeScript compiler knows about them:

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
```

Make sure you've installed jQuery as well:

```
npm install --save jquery
```

And included the script from your HTML page:

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

Your tsconfig file will look under the node_modules/@types folder by default to resolve types. Assuming, you haven't changed the defaults, it should automatically resolve the jQuery types properly at compile-time.