# Error When Importing jQuery Plugin into TypeScript/Ionic2 Project

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, jquery-plugins, ionic2

I'm importing jQuery into an Ionic2 project. I'm trying to use a jQuery plugin and it messes up the loading of the script when I include it.

I've commented out almost everything except for a few lines. This works:

```
import * as $ from '../lib/jquery/jquery.min';
(<any>window).$ = $;
```

However, when I add the jQuery plugin, the app breaks with "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined". Here's the code that causes it to break:

```
import * as $ from '../lib/jquery/jquery.min';
(<any>window).$ = $;
import '../lib/ripple/ripple.min';
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

***Solved*** Kind of. I just added var $ = require('jquery'); to the top of the plugin file and changed the jQuery import to import * as $ from 'jquery'; I'm still interested in any proper answers any of you might be able to offer.

Comment: Have you tried this (my answer): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42194540/angular-2-used-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have imported jQuery in my project.

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

The way you have imported it later (mentioned in `solved`) is the correct way of importing it.

You also need to inform this to TypeScript compiler using `npm install @types/jquery --save`.